# How broad is my fire cone breath?

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, races, area-of-effect

What is the width of the cone fire breath of the [Drakin](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Drakin_(5e_Race)) (a homebrewed race)? I know it's however long, but how wide is it at the end of the cone? Is it wide enough to maybe hit multiple targets?

Comment: Your question might be answered here: [How do I map a 15' cone to a 1" grid?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46492)

Comment: FYI: The Drakin is a homebrew race (i.e. custom, made by some random person on the internet) and isn't actually published materials. See the bottom category bar. Dandwiki is full of homebrew stuff.

Answer (score 9):

Cone-shaped breath weapons follow the rules for cone-shaped effects. These are found on page 204 of the PHB in the Spellcasting section. In particular, it reads

> A cone's width at a given point along its length is equal to that point's distance from the point of origin.

Thus, it will take up multiple squares and potentially hit multiple targets.

Comment: Perhaps of some interest: this results in an angle of `2*arctan(.5)` - roughly 53°.